# Copy build artifacts to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the Azure File Copy tasks in DevOps to copy the artifacts from Git to a Blob storage that sits under my subscription:

[image]

However the Azure File Copy tasks never completes. The task continues to run. I'm wondering if it's because of permission issue where my subscription can't write to the Blob storage. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@5
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_ADF-MRSG-Tide-Continuous-Integration-Build/ArmTemplates'
    azureSubscription: 'BDAP-PRD-PIPELINE-CONN (xxxxxxxx)'
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: mrsgtideprdwedev
    ContainerName: 'azure-artifacts'
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Log information:

```
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4423974Z ##[section]Starting: AzureBlob File Copy
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550000Z ==============================================================================
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550253Z Task         : Azure file copy
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550388Z Description  : Copy files to Azure Blob Storage or virtual machines
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550590Z Version      : 5.210.1
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550713Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4550863Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy
2023-01-12T17:01:15.4551268Z ==============================================================================
2023-01-12T17:01:20.7123632Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.0.1\Az.Accounts\2.10.4\Az.Accounts.psd1 -Global
2023-01-12T17:01:22.8437792Z ##[warning]Both Az and AzureRM modules were detected on this machine. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide
2023-01-12T17:01:31.6898708Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2023-01-12T17:01:32.5179394Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2023-01-12T17:01:32.5180271Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant xxx -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2023-01-12T17:01:35.1239900Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId xxx -TenantId xxx
2023-01-12T17:01:36.0411697Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.0.1\Az.Resources\6.3.1\Az.Resources.psd1 -Global
2023-01-12T17:01:39.1422423Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.0.1\Az.Storage\5.0.0\Az.Storage.psd1 -Global
2023-01-12T17:01:41.0099745Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.0.1\Az.Compute\5.0.0\Az.Compute.psd1 -Global
2023-01-12T17:01:44.7529810Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Modules\az_9.0.1\Az.Network\5.0.0\Az.Network.psd1 -Global
2023-01-12T17:01:45.5713749Z ##[warning]The names of some imported commands from the module 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Network' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
2023-01-12T17:01:45.8587032Z ##[warning]The names of some imported commands from the module 'Az.Network' include unapproved verbs that might make them less discoverable. To find the commands with unapproved verbs, run the Import-Module command again with the Verbose parameter. For a list of approved verbs, type Get-Verb.
2023-01-12T17:11:24.8085548Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2023-01-12T17:11:24.8364623Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2023-01-12T17:11:24.9976554Z ##[error]This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:0e6ffe85-601e-0047-3da8-2639da000000
Time:2023-01-12T17:11:24.5146395Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:0e6ffe85-601e-0047-3da8-2639da000000
Time:2023-01-12T17:11:24.5146395Z</Message></Error>

Headers:
x-ms-request-id: 0e6ffe85-601e-0047-3da8-2639da000000
x-ms-client-request-id: 069ac45e-6638-4d55-9ece-39522ed6f5c5
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationFailure
Content-Length: 246
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2023 17:11:24 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

2023-01-12T17:11:25.0733282Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureBlob File Copy
```

Comment: Hi Brian. 
1.Could you mask your subscription information in the screenshots?
2.Could you share the details logs of your
3.Have you checked the firewall or whitelist or ip restriction of your storage account?
4.Have you checked if your service connection have enough permission to the storage account (`Storage Blob Data Contributor` and storage `contributor`)?

Comment: Hi. I've masked the information and also added log info.